# Need help in Print task in ArcGIS JSAPI 3.2/3.3

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing, arcgis-desktop

I am using print task in my code and using dynamic map service layer and graphics layer (not using feature service layer) and I am able to print the map but it’s not displaying info window and graphics in the print out.

So any help will be great!!

Complete code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrZDn/) (I removed my server name)

What I am trying:

1. I am going though [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/widget_print.html) example in which I found that they are using graphics  layer +  feature layer and graphics is coming while printing the map
2. Replaced with ESRI sample REST service for the print task  still not getting the graphics and info-window
3. Researching on my side

### [image: screenshot 1 : with graphics and info window]

[image: screenshot 2: after performing print task]

Software’s: ArcGIS for Server and Desktop version 10.1 and JSAPI version 3.2/3.3

Comment: have you properly set up the proxy page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into a bug in the printTask. Check this esri forum post
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/61448-Problen-with-the-Print-Task?p=254619#post254619

For labeling, I worked around this by adding another separate graphic layer:
1. You can get esri.symbol.TextSymbol to show up by creating another graphic layer and adding it to that layer
2. FYI, the offset and alignment are ignored on the TextSymbol

I don't know if that will help with infowindows/popups...

Also, more here http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/75263-Print-TextSymbol?highlight=print+graphic

Comment: thanks for your reply and detailed information. I will check and let you know soon. thanks : )